# Sending AJAX Function List Item Dragged and Dropped from First List to Second List

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

I have the following JS code:

```
$("#list-one, #list-two").sortable({
   connectWith: '#list-two',
      start: function () {
         sender = $(this);
         recvok = false;
      },
      over: function () {
         recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
      },
      stop: function () {
         if (!recvok)
            $(this).sortable('cancel');

         $.ajax({
            url: '/process-list-element',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'list_element_name': $(this).find('h6').text()},
         });
      }
   }).disableSelection();
```

The drag and drop works fine but in the AJAX function the "this" keyword refers to the entire list instead of the list element that was dragged and dropped. I need to send the name of the list element that was dragged and dropped to function process-list-element, not the entire list. For your information, function process-list-element is being triggered appropriately when a list element is dragged and dropped. Is there a way I can access the list element from the "this" keyword? If it helps any, the list is just an unordered HTML list comprised of ul and li tags. A snippet of the HTML can be found below:

```
<ul id="list-one" class="connectedSortable">
   <li class="inner-pad">
      <h6>Blah blah blah</h6>
      <div class="content-div">
         <span>Blah blah blah</span>
         <p>Blah blah blah</p>
         <i>$32.95</i>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the default parameters passed to the "start", "stop" and "over" events? Try this, `start( event, ui )`. The `ui.item` is what you are looking for.
Also read [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/)

Comment: ui.item is a JQuery object. How do I extract values from it?

Comment: can you show your html ?

Comment: I've shown a snippet of HTML above.

Comment: use console.log(ui.item) to print the object. You can find the result in the developer tools conosle of your browser. Read about developer tools and how to use it. It is a very useful tool to specially debug your code. 
Can you show the result of console.log here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` to get element text i.e : `<h6>` tags . Here , `item` represent  current dragged element so using this you can access elements(childrens) inside it.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#list-one, #list-two").sortable({
  connectWith: '#list-two',
  start: function() {
    sender = $(this);
    recvok = false;
  },
  over: function() {
    recvok = ($(this).not(sender).length != 0);
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var text = ui.item.find("h6").text() //get h6 text
    console.log(text)
    console.log(ui.item.find("i").text()) //get i text
    if (!recvok)
      $(this).sortable('cancel');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/process-list-element',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        'list_element_name': text //pass same
      },
    });
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="list-one" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="inner-pad">
    <h6>Blah blah blah</h6>
    <div class="content-div">
      <span>Blah blah blah</span>
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <i>$32.95</i>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="inner-pad">
    <h6>Blah blah blah245</h6>
    <div class="content-div">
      <span>Blah blah blah</span>
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <i>$32.9</i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul id="list-two" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="inner-pad">
    <h6>Blah blah2554 blah</h6>
    <div class="content-div">
      <span>Blah blah blah</span>
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <i>$95</i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```